# git: Cloning into 'whatever'

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout and build source code.  I run this git command and receive the subsequent output:

```
> git clone https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb.git 
Cloning into 'lmdb'...
```

But nothing happens.  No lmdb is created anywhere.  Same things happens with other software.  What am I doing wrong?

I tried this:

```
> setenv GIT_TRACE 1
> git clone https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb.git
Defaulting to tracing on stderr...
09:14:28.588438 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb.git'
Cloning into 'lmdb'...
09:14:28.652990 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb.git'
```

Comment: Works fine here. And you don't get any further output or error message? Try running `GIT_TRACE=yes git clone https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb.git` to get some more information about what is going on and either interpret it yourself or post the result in an edit to your question.

Comment: Does it hang at that point? or return to the command prompt?

Comment: It does not hang.  It returns to the prompt.

Comment: Actually I mean `GIT_TRACE=1`, but it will not show much different result. This is all? That seems really strange. What is the return code if you run the `clone` command?

Comment: Same thing happens for "git clone https://github.com/gflags/gflags.git" and any other software I try to clone.

Comment: > git clone
You must specify a repository to clone.

Comment: If the last comment should be the answer to my question, I meant of course not doing an invalid `clone` command, but the full command we are talking about. Besides that you also didn't mention the return code.

Comment: Return code?  You mean like 1 or 0?

Comment: That looks as though you are not able to establish a data connection to the other Git. In other words, your Internet-phone-call is not going through. Check the wires on your Internet. :-) More specifically, make sure you can reach the other host—a GitHub server, in this case—normally, via whichever port(s) you are using. Https uses port 443. Is your firewall, if any, configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing. I'm behind a proxy so I fixed the problem by configuring GIT's proxy settings:

```
git config --global http.proxy <proxy server URL>
git config --global https.proxy <proxy server URL>
```